# Filtering records in GeoPackage file by numeric/text fields using GeoPandas/Fiona

Tags: gdal, geopandas, filter, geopackage, fiona

I have a GPKG file of 46M records and 6.5GB filesize, and need to open about 300 records, where `fieldX = Y` (`Y` may change). Opening the entire file would cause memory overflow, while processing the entire file in chunks would take a couple of hours.

I walked through [GDAL Python API docs](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#python-api), but there's nothing. Filtering seems to be done by calling a method rather than passing a parameter to [Open](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Open).

If it's possible to open the file in Fiona and then call a method to filter records (`.filter()`), that would work too.

Of course, I can find workarounds, but would like to have it rather straightforward.

**edit:** I tried Fiona's `.filter()` with `where` argument ([Iterator source](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/a6ed5b2e6972e4dad438b85e6f4b4ac8db1154c6/fiona/ogrext.pyx#L1482), [.filter source](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/a6ed5b2e6972e4dad438b85e6f4b4ac8db1154c6/fiona/collection.py#L371), [OGR docs](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#where)), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import Point

ds = (
    (Point(0, 0), 'abcde'),
    (Point(1, 1), 'fghij'),
    (Point(2, 2), 'klmno')
)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(ds, columns=['geometry', 'fieldX'])
gdf.to_file('test.gpkg', driver='GPKG')

with fiona.open('test.gpkg', layername='test') as fp:
    itr1 = fp.filter(where="fieldX='klmno'")
    print(next(itr1))

    itr2 = fp.filter(where="fieldX like '%klmno%'")
    print(next(itr2))
```

outputs:

```
{'type': 'Feature', 'id': '1', 'properties': OrderedDict([('fieldX', 'abcde')]), 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (0.0, 0.0)}}
{'type': 'Feature', 'id': '1', 'properties': OrderedDict([('fieldX', 'abcde')]), 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (0.0, 0.0)}}
```

In Sqlite3 this works as expected:

```
sqlite> .open notebooks/test.gpkg
sqlite> .tables
gpkg_contents           gpkg_spatial_ref_sys    rtree_test_geom_node  
gpkg_extensions         gpkg_tile_matrix        rtree_test_geom_parent
gpkg_geometry_columns   gpkg_tile_matrix_set    rtree_test_geom_rowid 
gpkg_ogr_contents       rtree_test_geom         test                  
sqlite> select * from test where fieldX='klmno';
3|GP|klmno
```

Comment: You can find lots of working Python code from the GDAL autotests  https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_gpkg.py. You want to read the layer with ExecuteSQL this way `sql_lyr = gpkg_ds.ExecuteSQL('SELECT * FROM "point_no_spi-but-with-dashes"')`. For making the query fast create index on fieldX. ExecuteSQL is certainly documented.

Comment: What if you try `filtered = filter(lambda f: f['properties']['fieldX']=='klmno', fp)`?

Comment: @Taras that works, but it first reads all the records into Python, and I want to avoid doing that (I have 46M records).

Comment: You may the approach suggested by @user30184, i.e. `from osgeo import ogr; gpkg_source = ogr.Open("test.gpkg",update=False); sql_layer = gpkg_source.ExecuteSQL("SELECT * FROM test WHERE fieldX = 'klmno'")`. What does it give?

Comment: that did work, thanks! I've submit a ticket to Fiona project though.

Comment: Shall we ask @user30184 to put his comment as a valid answer, do not we?